# SQL Statement Inner Join + Others...So join within a join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following SQL statement where I am adding game inventory and ordered inventory and then selecting the games that have that total inventory below the reorder point. The only problem is that I also want to select the game inventory below the reorder point that does not have any ordered inventory. I tried messing with the Having line where ItemIDs don't match, but no luck. Here is the current working code.

What I have:

```
SELECT tblGames.ItemID, tblGames.Title, ABS(tblGames.Inventory + Sum(tblSupplyOrders.Inventory)) AS UpdatedInventory
FROM tblGames
INNER JOIN tblSupplyOrders
ON tblGames.ItemID=tblSupplyOrders.ItemID
Group By tblGames.ItemID, tblGames.Title, tblGames.Inventory, tblGames.ReorderPoint
Having ABS(tblGames.Inventory + Sum(tblSupplyOrders.Inventory)) < tblGames.ReorderPoint
```

What I also want to display with it:

```
SELECT tblGames.ItemID, tblGames.Title, tblGames.Inventory
FROM tblGames
INNER JOIN tblSupplyOrders
ON tblGames.ItemID=tblSupplyOrders.ItemID
Group By tblGames.ItemID, tblGames.Title, tblGames.Inventory, tblGames.ReorderPoint
Having tblGames.Inventory < tblGames.ReorderPoint
```

***...where there is no tblSupplyOrders.ItemID***

Thanks in advance!

### Update Requested

tblGames includes:

- ItemID int, auto PK
- Title varchar(100)
- Inventory int,
- ReorderPoint int

tblSupplyOrders includes:

- SupplyOrder int, auto PK
- ItemID int, FK to tblGames
- Inventory int

So if:

- tblGames/tblSupplyOrders.ItemID = The Same #
- tblGames.Inventory = 2
- tblSupplyOrders.Inventory = 3
- tblGames.ReorderPoint = 6
- Output will include this game.
- The problem: It won't detect this game if there is no matching ItemID in tblSupplyOrders.

Comment: can you provide table structure??

Comment: And also sample data and your expected output based on that data would help

Comment: Prefer sqlfiddle link.

Comment: Had trouble with sqlfiddle, but hopefully the update info above is enough?

Comment: ... Why is every table prefixed with `tbl`?  Why is the game table id `ItemId`?  Why isn't it `SupplyOrderId`? (I'm also assuming you're not including incredibly necessary things like ordered-on, fulfilled-on, paid-on dates, etc for brevity purposes).

Comment: The tbl prefix is just a standard in this class. The ItemID is related to another table where we are working with for checkouts. And yeah, fortunately the project doesn't require that much detail like you're assuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things:

```
SELECT tg.ItemID, tg.Title, tg.Inventory
FROM tblGames tg
LEFT JOIN (
    select ItemID, sum(inventory) as Inventory
    from tblSupplyOrders 
    group by ItemID) tso
ON tg.ItemID=tso.ItemID
where tg.Inventory+coalesce(tso.Inventory,0) < tg.ReorderPoint
```

This will left-join `tblGames` to a subquery of `tblSupplyOrders` that aggregates all orders for a particular item.  This will return all rows from `tblGames` and matching rows of order aggregate from `tblSupplyOrders`, with nulls where there is no matching `tso` row.

The expression `tg.Inventory+coalesce(tso.Inventory,0)` calculates current inventory + pending orders; the `coalesce` is needed to deal with cases where there is no `tso` row, substituting zero instead of null for pending orders.

Comment: I think the implication from `tblSupplyOrders` is that he could have multiple rows (orders) outstanding, so he probably needs that table `GROUP`ed/`SUM`med.

Comment: Edit Collision!! @Clockwork-Muse I re-added your group-by. Thanks.

Comment: Ah I think this is what I want, but I'm trying to solve a little error it generates:
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 7
No column name was specified for column 2 of 'tso'.